# How to get Total amount of current items on every page in Pdfmake?

Tags: javascript, pdfmake

I'm using pdfmake to create pdf, so i want to know how to get total amount of items on the current page and maybe put the Total on the footer. for example:

| Name | Price |
| --- | --- |
| item 1 | 250 |
| item 2 | 300 |
| item 3 | 500 |

Then the footer will be (Total 1050)

next page

| Name | Price |
| --- | --- |
| item 1 | 150 |
| item 2 | 200 |
| item 3 | 100 |

Then the footer will be (Total 450)
and so on.

How do i do that using pdfmake because i can only get page numbers but not Totals.

Thank you

Comment: Pdfmake just makes PDFs. It's up to your normal javascript code to calculate things.

Comment: @EmilKarlsson i understand that but my items are dynamic, they appear in many pages, what i want is to get total on the current page using only items that appears on that page.

Comment: If your table spans multiple pages, and you tell Pdfmake to decide for you where to make the split from one page to the next, then you can not get the total per page (unless you know for sure how many rows Pdfmake will create per page). What you could do instead is that you define how many rows each page should have and then calculate the (sub)total of those rows on each page.

Comment: make sense, i was thinking maybe there's a function that can check the end of the page then it calculate. something like an event to check if the page breaks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [footer function](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/document-definition-object/headers-footers/) provided by pdfmake. A great example of how to get the total amount of items on the current page and put the total on the footer can be found here! https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/1441